# Random Number Seed Generator: Using System On Time

Tags: c, security, encryption, random, rsa

I'm trying to understand why this code is a security flaw. From my understanding, it is not safe to generate a random number seed using the system time when the program is turned on, but how is that guessable? I'm not sure I see a possible exploit.

*Code example removed due to DMCA Request by D. Wagner*

Comment: Someone can us `ps` to find out when the process was started, and that will make it easier for them to guess the seed.

Comment: Note that although you say 'add to that the number of milliseconds', you simply assign the number of microseconds divided by 128 to the seed; that leaves you with at most 13 bits of randomness in the seed (one million is about 20 bits; you shift 7 of those away, leaving the less random 13 bits).

Answer (score 3):

For a start, your code has a bug where it doesn't use the value in `time_in_sec` at all - it overwrites that in the following line:

```
seed = time_micro_sec >> 7;
```

Further, `time_micro_sec` only has 1000000 possible values, and after right-shifting by 7 that reduces to only 7813 possible values.  This space is trivial to search through by brute-force.

Even if you fix these bugs, at the end of the day the `srand()` / `rand()` random number generator is just not a cryptographically-strong PRNG.  The interface is ultimately limited by the fact that `srand()` takes an `unsigned int` argument, which on common platforms limits the entropy in the initial state to just 32 bits.  This is insufficient to prevent a brute-force attack on the seed.

Do not use `srand()` / `rand()` for security-critical random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you could predict what the system time is when you run the program (which is not a stretch if you're the one running the program), then you can predict the value fed into the seed and thus determine what the "random" number generator will generate.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the outright bug, which I assume is not intentional...

You don't have to predict the exact time for this to be a problem - just the rough when.  For any given seed, the random values generated are a completely predictable sequence.  So, if you repeatedly make actions, you can attempt to deduce which seed matches the pattern you're seeing If you can narrow down your start time to within a minute, say, that's only 60,000 seeds to search over (assuming milliseconds, though you mix comments about millis, variables named micros, and values which don't appear to be either), which might be simple. A day is only 86,400,000 - larger, but doable.

If I have the power to, e.g. crash your application and force a restart, it becomes MUCH easier to predict your seed, and then further exploit it.  If not, if you have local access, finding the start time is straightforward. If it's a remote attack, it may be harder, but, e.g. on an MMO, server restarts might be predictable, your bank may do service updates Sunday from 10PM to 4AM, etc. - all of which leak start times.

Basically: if you want something secure, use something that's designed to be secure in the first place.